# How do client certificates work?

Tags: ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I am working with a REST service provider and they want me to use a client certificate provided by them when making HTTP call.

How does a client cert achieve authentication?
If someone has a copy of the client cert, they too can be authenticated right?
Does a client cert offer anything else beside authentication?
How are they different from a username/password authentication?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How does a client cert achieve authentication?

By being either signed by someone the peer trusts (including self-signing), or signed by someone that is trusted by someone the peer trusts, etc.

> If someone has a copy of the client cert, they too can be authenticated right?

Wrong. They would also need the private key.

> Does a client cert offer anything else beside authentication?

No.

> How are they different from a username/password authentication?

Much more secure. No password-guessing is possible.

***However*** There is ***no such thing*** as a 'client certificate provided by them'. The process of generating a client certificate starts with ***you.*** You generate a key pair and a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and you have it signed by a CA. Or you generate a self-signed certificate. *You* then provide *your* certificate to *them.* If they are proposing to carry out all these steps and provide the resulting key pair and certificate to you, they do not know what they are talking about and should be severely chastised for security breaches. A private key is only private if no-one else has a copy.

Comment: Thanks. How does a server authenticate client after the client gives the public key via the certificate? In other words, what is the private key of the client cert used for?

Comment: The client provides not only his certificate but a digital signature over the certificate (and some other stuff) signed by his private key. The server verifies that with the public key. That proves that the client owns that certificate, but only if nobody else has, or has had, access to the private key. That's why 'provided by them' is completely and utterly invalid and insecure. They can't generate a certificate without a private key, and if they generate the private key it isn't private.

Comment: An SSL certificate isn't much different than a username/password. They're both just stuff you know that no one else is supposed to know. An SSL cert, at its core, it just an asymmetric key-pair (public/private key); it can be brute-force guessed just like a username/password pair.

Comment: @Granger There are major differences. An SSL certificate is not a secret, and a certificate signed by someone else alsoo carries someone else's verification of your identity.

Comment: @EJP - I consider the concept of an SSL cert to include the private key (e.g. a .pfx vs a .cer). As for the identity issue, everything in security hinges on the trust involved in that initial exchange, whether it be symmetric or asymmetric encryption in use. And just like any other "secret number" in computers, they can be brute-force attacked. Asymmetric keys are longer than symmetric because they're easier to crack (e.g. 2048 vs 128). They both have their place and are very useful.

Comment: @Granger You can consider what you like, but the SSL certificate that is sent from a server to a client doesn't contain the private key.